# How to have Custom ids in prisma / postgresql?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, database-design, prisma

I am using Prisma + PostgreSQL for my data. So far, I have been using ids generated by Prisma:

```
id             String           @id @default(cuid())
```

However, I'd like to use my own ids, something like `ABCD-WXYZ`, as my data will not grow so much and I'd like to have shorter ids and be able to see what the item is about using the id (e.g. `PULP-FICT` might represent the film Pulp Fiction, and I would easily be able to remember it this way.

How can I achieve this with Prisma + PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually specify `id` values and not have any `default` like this:

```
id        String   @id
```

In such a case, you would have to manually specify the `id` field when creating a new object. If you'd like to use some arbitrary database function to generate default values for the field, you can also take a look at [`dbgenerated()`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#dbgenerated).